# Как добавить приложение в список возможных приложений для вызова

Tags: java, android

В стандартной телефонной книге, отображаются контакты с возможностью  позвонить им через стандартное приложения и к примеру, через `Viber`. 
Вопрос: там могут отображаться только `VoIP` клиенты или и другие тоже, и если да то как это сделать. 
Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нагуглил вам ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293864/how-to-include-my-application-as-a-dialing-option-when-calling-from-the-addressb

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, что именно мне нужно сделать?

Comment: добавить своему приложению определенный интент-фильтр

Comment: @metalurgus, ну и оформили б как ответ

Comment: @hardsky, я полный ответ дать не могу, только знаю, в какую сторону копать. Может, если не дуст никто, отвечу позже, когда будет время